# Not load/send javascript to mobile client. - HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Javascript files tend be on the higher side of size, even when compressed. I have a website that looks great on the Desktop thanks to javascript and I'm not worried about size there. But on the mobile even an extra 50 KB is hefty, so I made a few css changes that make the mobile look great, but now all the javascript files are being sent as well (to the mobile), even though there is not need for them any more.

Is there a way for me to disable all the senting of javascript files if the client is a has a mobile ID?

Comment: Why not fix your CSS for desktop users as well, so you don't need the JavaScript at all?

Comment: Because the mobile site looks really really simple compared to what the desktop version does. That makes the css simple, whereas the desktop version is full fledge and has a real need for javascript.

Comment: Are you targeting specific devices (IOS/Andriod) or targeting every mobile browser?

Comment: Mobile in general, but iOS/Android should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of ways you could approach this, via a server-side library like [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) or even a simple user agent check and using a gateway method to load scripts

```
var is_mobile = navigator.userAgent.match(/android|iphone/ig);

var require = function(src, success, failure, force_load){
    if( is_mobile && !!force_load ){ return; }

    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.async = true; script.type = 'text/javascript'; script.src = src;
    script.onload = success || function(e){};
    script.onerror = failure || function(e){};
    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(script);
}

// loaded just for desktop
require('js/desktop-script.js', function(){ // onload
    // desktop only script
}, function(){ // onerror
    console.log("Something went wrong loading this script");
});

// loaded for desktop and mobile
require('js/jquery.js', function(){ // onload
    // desktop and mobile script
}, function(){ // onerror
    console.log("Something went wrong loading this script");
}, true);
```